# What is Lefty talking about when he says "What kind of a man has a malvole"?

Tags: dialogue, donnie-brasco

In the movie *Donnie Brasco*,

Lefty says to Donnie after being introduced to Richie Gazzo:

> What kind of a man has a malvole? He won't provide for his own wife.

Is he talking about the bar, the car, a goomar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An [early (1992) draft of the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Donnie-Brasco.html) gives us some more explanation. Lefty thinks the guy is cheap and he's not impressed that he's talking smack about his own wife.

> **LEFTY:** *You gonna put any money in this?*
>
> **CALVINO:** *First class all the way, Left-- that was my original plan. Then the minute I opened the joint I discovered I had partners--these goombahs. 'Gimme two hundred.' 'Gimme three hundred.' I said, 'Hey--I got a wife for that'*
>
> [Lefty shoots him a withering look.]
>
> **LEFTY:** *Wait here.*
>
> ...
>
> **DONNIE:** *So whaddaya think?*
>
> **LEFTY:** *I hate Neapolitans. You vouch for this guy, Donnie?*
>
> **DONNIE:** *Like any body else. I knew him ten years ago, he was okay then.*
>
> **LEFTY:** **What kind of man begrudges his wife?**
>
> **DONNIE:** *Look, I'm just making the introduction. You make the decision.*

---

The [1997 (redraft) of the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/donnie-brasco-1997.pdf) has that line in full. It's not 'malvole', it's *'male voglia'*, literally ['*ill will*'](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qhWY_shL4N0C&pg=RA53-PA5&lpg=RA53-PA5&dq=%22male+voglia%22+in+italian&source=bl&ots=j2slwTufrL&sig=ACfU3U0f_1V36tWWLAAFLlFRtYjFCKxGGg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBieikqYuBAxUxV0EAHfYMALU4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22male%20voglia%22%20in%20italian&f=false) in Italian

> **LEFTY:** *What kind of man has a* [underlined] ***male voglia*** [underlined] *he don't want to provide for his wife?*
>
> **DONNIE:** *What, Richie? He's okay.*

Answer (score 2):

> Is he talking about the bar, the car, a goomar?

He's talking about Richie's attitude. About the man itself, and his weakness. "*Malvole*" can be translated into "*someone who's forced into doing things against his own will*". When they meet, Richie complains about people taking money from him, and jokes about his wife who could do the same.

Donnie is proud to be "*one of them*", a man you don't force into anything. He instantly belittles Richie because he sees him as a weak person, not able to protect his business, make money, and can give his wife enough money so that she won't need anything or complain ("*what's this dump?!*"). Like in *The godfather*, a real man has to take care of his wife/family, Richie doesn't seem to do that, and Donnie instantly dispises him for not standing his ground against adversity.

From the [script - pages 66 & 76](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/donnie-brasco-1997.pdf):

> Richie called me up, he's getting
> hassled by some half-assed wiseguys.
> He needs a partner who can give him
> peace of mind. He has a nightclub
> down there.
>
> Gazzo: hadda shut the doors. The way these bums had their hands in my pockets. Two hundred bucks for
> this, three hundred bucks for that. I got a wife for that!